# AmqpItemReader and Dead Letter Queue

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement a job that reads messages from a queue and move them to dead letter when an error occurs. I've tried to use a transacted channel but it always requeue the message.

Is there any automatic way to do that with Spring Batch when an exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, refer to Spring AMQP about [Dead Lettering](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling).

There is `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` which you can inject into the `RabbitTemplate` for the `AmqpItemReader`. So, all those `.receive()` will be wrapped with the retry advice and in case of exhausting the message will be rejected to the configured DLX.

Comment: Is this still the case? I cannot find any methods on the rabbitTemplate that take in a MessageRecoverer

Comment: That's correct. There is a `setRecoveryCallback(RecoveryCallback<?> recoveryCallback)` instead. But more I'm looking into this, more I think that my answer is wrong. If `RabbitTemplate.receive()` fails, there is just no message to recover. The retry must be applied in the next batch step. I assume it is a processor.